# HTTP proxy able to redirect requests selectively

Tags: redirect, proxy

Is there a proxy with selective redirection capabilities? For example, let's say we have a server S, with two files A and B. When requesting file A with a browser: `http://S/A.html` I want to redirect this request to file `http://localhost/A.html` (I want to serve my local version of `A.html` instead of the remote one). When requesting file B: `http://S/B.html` I want to get the remote version, so the redirection filter must be selective.

Is there a tool for windows, able to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Squid is available for Windows and supports rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

The [autoresponder](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp) feature of Fiddler does exactly what is asked.